# How to get subfolders to show up in favorites inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a shared mailbox to which one user has added a couple of subfolders in Outlook. Another user uses her mailboxes exclusively in the favorites view.

Is it possible to have the emails in the subfolder show up in the inbox when navigating there via favorites?

We're using Outlook 2010 and Exchange 2013.

Comment: No, but you there are several ways to add shared folders where the subfolders will appear by default if they are shared as well.

This Microsoft video will explain best: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/showcase/details.aspx?uuid=17dcb0c4-9fba-4b91-85ad-3d833bf42c74 or same video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKspKy5FsXE&feature=youtu.be  -- I'm not going to post as answer because I don't want to rehash the steps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nope, Favorites are single folders marked as favorites. The general idea is to separate them out from the pile of folders, making the more visible (and easier to access).

If the subfolders were included, that'd go against this idea.

Sounds like you're trying to find a technical workaround for a human problem. ;)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do:)

Comment: Then you're probably better off fixing the human with some training instead.  "I didn't see that because I don't like using that view" shouldn't fly if it's affecting workflow, procedure and/or eating IT's time (just think, you're going to have to maintain any hack you my come up with, which will be awesomely fun in 3-5 years, I'm sure). ;)

Comment: The problem in this case is one user prefers having things one way, and the other user wants it another way. Since I can't accommodate both they'll have to compromise which usually means the user with seniority gets her way;p

Comment: @DomAdmin Well good luck with that. :/ Keep in mind, sometimes you're allow to just tell people "no that can't be done", and then let them come up with some alternative ideas they both agree with.  But anyway, that's outside of SU's scope. ;)